# Primitive types are also class objects?

Tags: java, class

While I was reading the `java.lang.Class` doc, I found  the following description:

```
  The primitive Java types ({@code boolean},
 * {@code byte}, {@code char}, {@code short},
 * {@code int}, {@code long}, {@code float}, and
 * {@code double}), and the keyword {@code void} are also
 * represented as {@code Class} objects.
```

Can somebody explain, what  is meant by "Primitive Java types are also represented as Class objects" ?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418202/why-do-primitive-types-have-a-class-and-how-is-it-intended-for-using and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271999/what-does-int-class-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197084/what-is-the-use-purpose-of-primitive-type-classes

Comment: @JonnyHenly I think they are not referring to the Boxed class. But I am not sure

Comment: @nantitv I thought it was referring to those when I first read it, but the questions Tunaki linked make much more sense.